# fatal error: 'eigen3/Eigen/Dense' file not found

Tags: macos, terminal, eigen

I tried to use eigen in mac.
After I installing it I run a demo from its' main page.The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{
 MatrixXd m(2,2);
 m(0,0) = 3;
 m(1,0) = 2.5;
 m(0,1) = -1;
 m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
 std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

And I write following code in terminal:

```
g++ -I usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/ aaa.cpp -o aaa
```

It turns out like that:

```
aaa.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'eigen3/Eigen/Dense' file not found
```

However I can run this code perfectly in Xcode.
Who can help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your include line to

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

or

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

and your command line to

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/eigen3 aaa.cpp -o aaa
```

I recommend also adding at least `-O1` to your command line, as soon as you compile any code with more than a few instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.Your way fix the problem perfectly.Can you tell me what dose "adding at least -O1 to my command line"means?

Comment: Change your command line command to `g++ -I /usr/local/include/eigen3 aaa.cpp -o aaa -O1` (or `-O2` instead of `-O1`). This makes a huge performance difference for non-trivial programs.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem when I use cmake and make on mac

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (Transformation)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)

message ("${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")
add_executable (Transformation main.cpp)
```

`mkdir build && cd build`
`cmake ..`
I get this

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000026
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000026
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
/usr/local/include/eigen3
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/xxxx/Documents/code/C++/homework0/build
```

`make`

```
/Users/xxxx/Documents/code/C++/homework0/main.cpp:2:9: fatal error: 
      'eigen3/Eigen/Core' file not found
#include<eigen3/Eigen/Core>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

while I use `g++ main.cpp -o Test` is OK.